# Remove pings or Availability Monitor from Logs on Rails - Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, heroku, ping, newrelic

How can I easily remove, or filter, requests from New Relic's Availability Monitor from the logs of my Rails application running on Heroku?

Since they ping the app every 30 seconds or so, my log data is extremely polluted with pings. I would like to exclude them from the logging and only check the Availability on New Relic's reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Rack::Middleware can help. It will silence any URL you configure: https://github.com/spagalloco/silencer